# MySql create few table with the same structure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to create 8 tables with the exact same structure. The easiest way is to copy-paste the code and apply different names for the tables. I want to be cool and create them with one cycle. How can I make that cycle and what is best way to apply the different names ? Thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html

Comment: Why create 8 tables with the exact same structure?  Why not create one table, with an additional column that differentiates the different types of info?

Comment: Because they'll be very large tables and I guess it's better if the data is splitted between the appropriate tables ? Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You're wrong, it's not better, there are other mechanisms that help you optimize larger tables - such as partitioning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fastest method for creating tables with duplicate structures would be as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tb1
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    ...,
    primary key (id)
);
create table tb2 like tb1;
create table tb3 like tb1;
create table tb4 like tb1;
...
create table tb8 like tb1;
```

This copies both the table structure and corresponding indexes.

If you need to make a table without indexes, this may be OK for you

```
CREATE TABLE tb1
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    ...,
    primary key (id)
);
CREATE TABLE tb2 AS SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE 1=2;
```

Depending on columns definitions, this may or may not work.

## CAVEAT

This cannot be do for a table with foreign key constraints. That would be done in stages.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE tb2 AS SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE 1=2;` this creates a myisam table even if source table type is different

Answer (score 1):

I believe the MySQL syntax is

```
CREATE TABLE <tablename> LIKE <extant table name>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  a INTEGER;
  b INTEGER;
);

CREATE TABLE B AS A; --WITH DATA added to end will copy both ddl and data. 
CREATE TABLE C AS A;
CREATE TABLE D AS A;
CREATE TABLE E AS A;
CREATE TABLE F AS A;
CREATE TABLE G AS A;
CREATE TABLE H AS A;
```

Although I'm suspicious about if you have a XY problem here. 8 tables with the same structure can be achieved more compactly  and in a structure the DBMS will be better able to manage with 1 table and a extra indicator attr to determine which of the 8 the current row belongs.

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  a INTEGER;
  b INTEGER;
  table_num INTEGER CHECK ( table_num >= 0 && table_num <= 7 ); 
)Primary Index(a,b,table_num)
Index(table_num);
```

Also I don't know sql-server all that well so all these statements may need to be adjusted for dialects, I'm not sure... But the general idea should be the same.